# When would non-binary datastructures be a good idea over binary ones? (ie. heaps, BST, etc)

Tags: algorithm

A lot of datastructures in CS are binary (BST, heaps, etc). What would be good reasons for implementing them in non-binary form? Ie. have a heap with 3 children for each nodes, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to choose RB tree, B-Tree or AVL tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589556/when-to-choose-rb-tree-b-tree-or-avl-tree)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It's really not. That question asks about specific tree data structures; this is a far more general question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trees with more than two children per node are a tradeoff, as they will have shallower depth at the expense of more links per node. The [B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), commonly used in databases and filesystems, is a classic example of a tree structure with multiple links per node. This structure fits well with filesystems because the size of the B-tree node can be tuned to match closely with the size of a filesystem block or cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Binary trees have relatively large space overhead. E.g., a node in a binary search tree implementing a set contains four fields, `key`, `left` and `right`. Since the `key` is the only thing you're really interested in and the `left` and `right` pointers are just bookkeeping for the data structure, that's 2/3 overhead.

By contrast, a ternary search tree node would have five fields: `key1` and `key2`, plus pointers `left`, `middle` and `right`. That's only 3/5 overhead, and with larger nodes, the relative amount of overhead decreases further. Of course, at some point, the structure will grow too large to be manageable, so there is a limit to the amount of performance that you can squeeze out of larger nodes; that limit depends on the application.

(I've not even considered the overhead caused by memory allocation, which also drops as nodes grow larger. There are also other reasons for having larger nodes, e.g. a [2-3 tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-3_tree) has better asymptotic complexity than a binary search tree.)

Answer (score 1):

When operations are binary, you would use binary data structures. When operations are ternary, you would use ternary data structures. One reason why Binary data structures are common is that most of the operations are binary. For e.g. if you want to compare 4 elements, you would compare 2 elements at a time. It's the same with `+,-,*,/`. Take for example TreeSet or TreeMap in Java which is a Red Black tree. You provide a Comparator to it and you implement:

```
compare(T o1, T o2)
```

Which is a binary operation comparing 2 arguments.